# Cross-thread operation not valid: VB.net I'm a noob..

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have two codes here separately it works but when i put it together i get the error "Cross-thread operation not valid". i tried to search the web how to solve this, i just don't get how to apply it in my codes.

[Cross-Thread operation not valid VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331009/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-vb-net)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1467258.aspx?Error+Cross+thread+operation+not+valid+Control+Listbox1+accessed+from+a+thread+other+than+the+thread+it+was+created+on+

CODE 1  use to Screen Shot my PANEL control.

```
  Private Sub CaptureSHOT(ctrl As Control, fileName As String)
    Dim bounds As Rectangle = ctrl.Bounds
    Dim pt As Point = ctrl.PointToScreen(bounds.Location)
    Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
        g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(pt.X - ctrl.Location.X, pt.Y - ctrl.Location.Y), Point.Empty, bounds.Size)
    End Using
    bitmap.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png)
End Sub
```

CODE 2  use to call my "CaptureShot" Function via timer when the FORM loads.

```
 Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    Dim tmr As New System.Timers.Timer()
    tmr.Interval = 2000
    tmr.Enabled = True
    tmr.Start()
    AddHandler tmr.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub CloseFormCallback()
Private Sub CloseForm()
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New CloseFormCallback(AddressOf CloseForm)
        Invoke(d, Nothing)
    Else
        Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnTimedEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
    CaptureSHOT(Panel1, "D:\SC\" & erk & ".png")
    CloseForm()
End Sub
```

The Error i'm getting
[image]

Comment: Let me guess: you looked for a ready-to-use code and weren't able to find one meeting your exact expectations? Some people might be surprised with such a situation (the ones defending ideas like: error = google it = get a working code). You have two options: continue looking for a magical solution (via online research or perhaps an answer here giving exactly what you need); or you might understand what "cross-thread operation not valid" means and learn about multithreading in order to be able to build proper codes not triggering so basic errors. In any case, this question is off-topic to me.

Comment: actually no, i just really want someone to explain it to me what thus it mean all the articles i've read seems so different to what i have in my code. if you could give me a proper explanation and example i would probably can do it.

Comment: This is a basic error (= off-topic here, IMO) which indicates that you are not understanding the underlying situation (= multithreading) properly. It is triggered because you are trying to affect from thread2 a variable which belongs to thread1. As said, I recommend you to do some basic learning on this front. Alternatively, you might wait here for a ready-to-use solution, but I will certainly not be the one delivering such a thing.

Comment: I'm struggling to see why you don't see that the two links you provided directly apply to your code. You are accessing a control from the non-UI thread. Do you think you're accessing `ctrl` from the UI thread??

Comment: There's tons of youtube-videos etc etc that explain this issue. You are not the first and not the last to ask this question, do your homework and google, everyone here did that at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geez you're all hostile today haha kidding aside thanks to Enigmativity and  varocarbas strict lecture i notice that i already have a "Private Delegate Sub" for my CloseFormCallback() and i keep getting an error because i was adding another "Private Delegate Sub" for my "CaptureShot" Function. now i just add the "CaptureSHOT(Panel1, "D:\SC\" & erk & ".png")" to my Private Delegate Sub CloseFormCallback(). and it works!

```
Private Delegate Sub CloseFormCallback()
Private Sub CloseForm()
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New CloseFormCallback(AddressOf CloseForm)
        Invoke(d, Nothing)
    Else
        CaptureSHOT(Panel1, "D:\SC\" & erk & ".png")
        Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There you go. A nice and simple solution.