# How can I solve this cross thread error?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, backgroundworker

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control textbox accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. vb.net

```
Sub autocompletepayee()

    Dim cmd2 As New Odbc.OdbcCommand
    Dim dr As Odbc.OdbcDataReader
    Dim myquery As String
    myquery = "select payee from tbrequest"
    cmd2.CommandText = myquery
    cmd2.Connection = con
    dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader

    While dr.Read
        txtPayee.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(dr.GetString(0)) 'this is the line where the error prompt

    End While
    dr.Close()
```

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331009/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-vb-net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, though it might be shorter if more were known about where the code was located

```
    Dim cmd2 As New Odbc.OdbcCommand
    Dim dr As Odbc.OdbcDataReader
    Dim myquery As String
    myquery = "select payee from tbrequest"
    cmd2.CommandText = myquery
    cmd2.Connection = con
    dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader

    While dr.Read
        If txtPayee.InvokeRequired Then
            txtPayee.Invoke(Sub()
                                txtPayee.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(dr.GetString(0)) 'this is the line where the error prompt
                            End Sub)
        Else
            txtPayee.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(dr.GetString(0)) 'this is the line where the error prompt
        End If

    End While
    dr.Close()
```