# VB form cross thread method call with parameters

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, delegates

I am writing a VB form application that redirects the standard output stream of a process and uses it in a UI.

I am having trouble calling methods with parameters that update controls on the form from the OutputHandler sub.

I can call a method without parameters like so

```
Me.Invoke(New MyDelSub(AddressOf ServerStarted))
```

Which works fine.

And a bit of googling told me that to call a method with parameters I should do this:

```
Dim del As JoinDelegate = AddressOf PlayerJoins
del.Invoke(username)
```

With this delegate and method pair:

```
Private Delegate Sub JoinDelegate(ByVal username As String)
Private Sub PlayerJoins(ByVal username As String)
   PlayersBox.Items.Add(username)
   'Do other stuff
End Sub
```

But this produces an IllegalOperationException the first time the method tries to access a control.

Comment: The question has been asked and answered multiple times. For example take a look at this post: [Cross-Thread operation not valid VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331009/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-vb-net). However using [Lambda Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) to solve the problem can be syntactically interesting.

Comment: Yeah, I read through a few of them, just couldn't figure out how to use that to pass parameters. Sorry for being stupid ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1)** Supposing you have a method like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(value1 As String, value2 As String)
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} {1}", value1, value2))
End Sub
```

You can call it using invoke this way:

```
Me.Invoke(Sub() DoSomething("Hello", "World!"))
```

**2)** If you want to make thread safe call to a control you can write the method this way:

```
Public Sub AddItemToListBox1(item As String)
    If (ListBox1.InvokeRequired) Then
        ListBox1.Invoke(Sub() AddItemToListBox1(item))
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    End If
End Sub
```

Then it's enough to call it in a the UI thread or in another thread the same way simply:

```
AddItemToListBox1("some item")
```

The call would be thread safe.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, can't believe I didn't see how to do that - spent hours messing around with delegates and all kinds of spaghetti code.
Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) - I believe it's the most readable and clean way.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
Private Sub SetControlText(control As Control, text As String)
    If control.InvokeRequired Then
        control.Invoke(New Func(Of Control, String)(AddressOf SetControlText), control, text)
    Else
        control.Text = text
    End If
End Sub
```

Call that method from any thread.